# Push int to String array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, push

I am using an autocomplete and I want to store the ID´s of the chosen users.

I want to store the IDs in an array of strings, and this array must only have unique values ​​(cannot have duplicate values)

I tried to push and convert values ​​(using tostring ()) but to no avail.

Can anyone get me some help?

The desired output (example): ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

**My code [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efy9hw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**COMPONENT**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      (val: any[]) =>{
        this.allFruits = val.map(user => {
      this.nameIdMap.set(user.username, user.id);
      return user.username
    });
        this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null); //use this to apply changes instantly
      } 
    )
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

arr:any;
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  var a = this.nameIdMap.get(event.option.viewValue);
  console.log(a);
  // var b = this.arr.push(a);
  // var c = b.map((input) => input).join(",").toString();
  // console.log(c)
  this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
  this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: "and this array must only have unique values" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

will be like this.

```
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  var a = this.nameIdMap.get(event.option.viewValue);
  //this makes sure selected id does not exist
  if( this.arr.filter(x => /*makes cast int to string to compare items*/ String(a) == x).length < 1) {
      this.arr.push(String(a));
      this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
  }
  console.log(a, this.arr);

  this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
}
```

make you sure arr variable is initialized since you declare it.

```
arr:any[] = [];
```

hope it be by helpful. D;

Answer (score 2):

Your array is declared, but never initialized. First you need to initialize it. And since you want it to be a string array you should declare it as such:

```
arr:string[] = [];
```

Then you need to convert your numbers to strings if you want to push them into that array. The `push` method doesn't return the array, so you have to keep referring to the field itself rather than capturing the result the way you're trying to do.

```
  this.arr.push(a.toString());
  var c = this.arr.map((input) => input).join(",").toString();
  console.log(c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I think your link is the same as the post. Push already works, now how do I pass this information to an array of strings?

Comment: I removed the link, since it's not necessary. Clarify your question: you don't "pass information" to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = new Set();
a.add(String(1));
console.log(Array.from(a)); // ["1"]
```

Comment: Can you break it down to the minimal code example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I have this in my demo, I can only get the ID´S correctly ... the rest of the code is commented because it is not working :(